# rescue not catch error 'Selenium::WebDriver::Error'

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rescue

When my code runs into `select_to_city(to)`,

I guess it will break by `Selenium::WebDriver::Error`

But it didn't stop be the rescue why ?

```
class Tiger123 < ClassTemplate
    def form_action(from, to, flight_date)
      begin
        select_to_city(to)
        select_depart_date(flight_date)
      rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error => e
        binding.pry
      rescue Exception => e
        binding.pry
      end
    end


def select_to_city(to)
  @driver.find_element(:id, "selDestPicker").click
  @driver.find_element(:id, to).click    
end
```

## UPDATE

Finally I added `rescue` in the select_to_city function

And it did working. I don't understand why it didn't rescue in the `form_action` method

```
def select_to_city(to)
begin
@driver.find_element(:id, "selDestPicker").click
@driver.find_element(:id, to).click          
rescue Exception => e
  binding.pry
end
end
```

Comment: You guess it will break? Does it? If it does what kind of Exception is thrown because no matter what it will be rescued by `Exception` unless it is not actually raising an exception.

Comment: @engineersmnky i'm sure the rescue not working at all. because I stopped at the 1st breakpoint before  select_to_city(to), then `continue`, then it didn't stop by the `breakpoint` after  `select_depart_date(flight_date)`

Answer (score 0):

Rescuing the `Selenium::WebDriver::Error` does not work because the exception is not of that class. `Selenium::WebDriver::Error` is only the module that includes the different error types.

During the rescue of the general `Exception`, you can see the exception class and its ancestors by using the `ancestors` method:

```
rescue Exception => e
  p e.class.ancestors
  #=> [Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError, Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError, StandardError, Exception, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
end
```

The first item in the array is the exception's class, which happens to be the specific error in Selenium. The next item, `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError`, is the parent class that all of the Selenium exceptions inherit from. It is this parent class that you want to rescue:

```
def form_action(from, to, flight_date)
  begin
    select_to_city(to)
    select_depart_date(flight_date)
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError => e
    binding.pry
  end
end
```